# requestHandler code for multiple core

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I created two core and they are showing http://{localhost}:8983/solr/ and which I click on them the admin panel is opened. The solr.xml files has below given code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true" >
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

And I create the folder accordingly. But when I try to add handler to it suppose to core1 in the core1->config->solrconfig.xml , the core0 disappears from the core list

The core for requesthandler is given below.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I even tried passing the core name with handler i.e

```
<requestHandler name="/core0/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

But it did not work.

Do I need to change something else in order to run two cores?

Comment: whats the url you are using to access them ?

Comment: http://192.168.1.48:8983/solr/core0/dataimport?command=full-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the core entry in the solrconfig.xml.

```
   <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

You can handle the data import for individual cores

core0 - `http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport`

core1 - `http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport`

Comment: Hi, This is the status message I am getting. 
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:0.296</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2011-11-18 11:04:25</str>
<str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
<str name="Rolledback">2011-11-18 11:04:25</str>
</lst>

Comment: and also I have to put requesthandler in solrconfig.xml of core0 otherwise 404 error